# How to configure SELinux for nginx to access a symlink to a mounted directory

Tags: nginx, selinux

I have a libvirt vm running nginx with a shared filesystem mounted in the nginx vm, and I want to expose a directory in that mount.  nginx seems to be running fine, and I can access the basic local files and subdirs in /usr/share/nginx/html.  I have a symlink from the mount to the default nginx location, via

```
ln -sf /mnt/h_drive/ss4/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

..and I can see the `ss4` dir from the browser, but when I click on it, I get the "403 Forbidden" and see the following in my /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2017/10/18 17:52:16 [error] 30806#0: *1 opendir() "/usr/share/nginx/html/ss4" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: _, request: "GET /opt/ss4/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

if I disable selinux with `setenforce 0` I can access everything.

What do I need to do to allow for accessing this mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually stumbled on the following as a solution:

```
semanage allow httpd_t nfs_t:dir read;
```

Thanks to @bell for the tips on troubleshooting, I definitely will be referencing them for future issues!

Answer (score 1):

## tips on troubleshooting..

## Install as root

$yum install setroubleshoot-server -y

$aureport -a # gives a report on denials

$ausearch -m avc -ts recent #last 10 min

## You should be able  to update policy

$sudo audit2allow -a

## You would see something similar for your own case when the above report is run.

nginx system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 5 file getattr unconfined_u:object_r:puppet_etc_t:s0 denied 616

## Create policy

$audit2allow -a -M read

## Make new policy active

$semodule -i read.pp